# How to: JQuery Colorpicker in a form in FLAT mode

Tags: javascript

I want JQuery Colorpicker to appear in a form in a Flat mode - allow my site users pick a color of choice.

So I did the following:
a. installed JQuery Colorpicker field
b. created a new custom module - to load a new form
c. In the form - created a color picker like this:

$form['element'] = array(
'#type' => 'jquery_colorpicker',
'#title' => t('Color'),
'#default_value' => 'FFFFFF',
);

d. Bingo! - the color picker appears as a button - and NOT as a flat mode.

e. Looking at sample code from when I make a dummy HTML file with following code, the plugin works perfectly:

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
    $('#picker').ColorPicker({
      flat:true,
      layout:'hex',
      submit:0
    });
  }
)
```

f. I tried the following without success:
1. Added a .js file to my module's .info file
2. Tried drupal_add_js() to include the file from my module
3. Added the script to my page.tpl.php

None of above has been successful - please help!

Thanks in advance!